# Best practice for running a process in background and wait until it's ready

Tags: shell, unix, travis-ci

The system:

- Backend Application (RESTful HTTP API) written in Java (Play Framework 2.3.x)
- Frontend Application (GUI, consuming the API) written in Javascript (angularjs with grunt for building)
- Travis CI is used for Continous Integration

The problem:

I want to start / run the backend application and after it's successfully started, I want to test it with protractor (through grunt tasks).

**But** starting the backend application will not continue because it is not a ending process (the server is running -> not ending)

Putting the server start as a backend process by adding a `&` could solve the problem, but then there is no guarantee that the server has started in the meanwhile.

Some advices in the internet say:

> Add sleep(x) and run your test after that

But how much is x?

**Is there another way to do that, rather than guessing (or measuring) the time to start the server and put a sleep after running the server start as background process?**

Edit:
The output of starting the server (for example to compare the output of the background task in a periodic way) is this:

```
$ activator run
[info] Loading project definition from ...
[info] Set current project to ... (in build file:...)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Comment: If the process to start the server launches a separate process and completes, then you can use `wait`. Otherwise, you could use an approach based on reading the output (e.g. wait until a certain message is printed).

Comment: @TomFenech yeah the second approach was what I originally thought. Do you have an example for that? I guess that could be an acceptable answer.

Comment: In order to do so, we would need to see a sample of the output from the startup process, indicating which part should indicate that the server had successfully been started.

Comment: @TomFenech I updated the question with the output, i think it is ok to compare the output with 'Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)' is ok

Comment: What about using "nohup" command ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do better than guessing or estimating how long to sleep before testing by a simple external test to see if the server is up, e.g.,

```
while ! curl -s 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000 >/dev/null; do
    sleep 1
done

# now start real tests
...
```